# NVD3 horizontal bar chart with categories of groups

Tags: d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Im starting NVd3 development and strugling with a big problem. I already finished my horizontal bar chart.

The problem is that the client asked me to regroup labels into groups, something like this: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/wp-content/img200804/DualCatBar.png

In that example you can see categories of parts. How can that be archieved suing NVD3 or D3?

Thank you for your help.